# E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, protractor

I do a simple test , I do a login , after that , I'm looking to test the text value of a string if it's exactly the sameon the expect .

Otherwise, I receive this error message:

> 'E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1'

Code:

```
it('Open StaPage', async () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    browser.sleep(3000);
    page.authUser('admin', 'password');
    await page.logIn();
    await page.getTitleText();
    console.log(page.getTitleText());
    expect(page.getTitleText()).toEqual('Title');
});
```

Comment: It would be helpful maybe if you explain what those `navigateTo()`, `authUser()`, etc, do. Also try to put the await before every line there, except the last one, the expect should be like this: `expect(await page.getTitleText()).toEqual('Title');`

Comment: yeah and it would be nice to see the full error stack

Comment: [12:01:00] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[12:01:00] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60721/devtools/browser/29b1ea99-41d4-401d-8f9c-6ab293a03308
[12:01:17] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[12:01:17] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[12:01:17] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[12:01:17] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1